# Can Someone please Explain me the reason why this is working , I defined a function inside dictionary

Tags: javascript, node.js, function

how it is working for both ? I gave string for one thing and for other I just gave reference but it is working for both **please look at draw and 'draw' it is working for both without any error may I know the reason behind it?**

```
k={
    draw:function(){
        console.log("drawing")
    }
}

p={
    'draw':function(){
        console.log("drawing 2")
    }
}
k.draw()
p.draw()
```

Comment: 'draw' is a property, so `draw` and `"draw"` are identical.  `function () {` is the function, it's just an anonymous function.

Answer (score 0):

when the first character of the key is not a number, object.key and object['key'] is same

Comment: It's not only numbers that you need quotes for.  Lots of other characters are not allowed in  a non-quoted property name.